# XP: how to know whether someone 'woke up' computer?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-access, event-log, teamviewer

I have been trying to connect all day via Teamviewer to a machine in a different town.  Now it suddenly works.  I think someone there may have walked by and moved the mouse to wake it up.

What logs etc. could I check to see if someone did that or not?  I'm trying to work out what happened because I need this link to be reliable.

I'm not sure what state the remote computer was in because Teamviewer asked for an authentication password but got no further, then in the mid afternoon it suddenly starts working for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually stored in the Event Viewer.

If you go to *Start*, *Run*, type in `eventvwr`, then when it opens go to *Security*, you should see something in there where it starts logging events when it wakes up.